# Use list comprehension with a double loop to append values based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

Here is my first code example.  How do I accomplish this using list comprehension?

```
for c in c_list:
    c_id_list.add(c.id)
```

Can I use list comprehension to accomplish this?

```
for c in c_list:  
    c.p_list = []
    for p in p_list:
        if p.c_id == c.id:
            c.p_list.append(p)
```

Comment: What is a _comprehensive list_? Please add an example of `c_list` and `p_list`.

Comment: @chepner In a sense, `c_list` is a list of lists because each item `c` in `c_list` has a list `c.p_list`.

Comment: Oh, duh. I'll blame generic-name-induced blindness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

```
c_id_list = [c.id for c in c_list]
```

2.

```
for c in c_list:  
    c.p_list = [p for p in p_list if p.c_id == c.id]
```

Comment: `if p.c_id is c.id` is incorrect. Do not use `is` instead of `==`, it is not performing an equality test.